# Call a function inside its own callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

My NodeJS application runs my C++ application and watches it. If application gets killed, server runs it again. If my application would run for days, will it cause stack overflow if hypothetically this kill/die scenario happen too many times? If yes, can you please provide a solution?

Thank you

```
import { execFile } from "child_process";

function runRedirector(){
    execFile("./redirector.out", ["1"], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    runRedirector();
    });
}
```

Comment: Call stack wont grow. Callbacks are async.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko This is what I needed to know. So my code is ok in NodeJS, right?

Comment: You code looks ok. Well, at least it would not explode call stack :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you. You may please add your response as answer so I can mark it as solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call stack would not grow due to async nature of `execFile`. By the time the callback got called the outer call would already be poped out of the callstack

```
const {execFile} = require("child_process");

let i = 0
function runRedirector(){
    execFile("./redirector.out", ["1"], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('In callback', i++)
      runRedirector();
    });
    console.log('In runDirector', i);  // this will be logged first
}
```